# how to let bootstrap component open after ajax with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap Collapse Component, inside the collaspe, there is a form to add or delete a Comment to a Todo

I am using `remote: true` in order to get ajax. The problem is when i submit the add or delete action, it close the collapse when it rerender, how to fix that please ?

here is my form

```
<ul>
  <% todo.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <li>
      <%= comment.content %>
      <%= link_to 'delete', comment_path(comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, remote: true %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

and here is my controller

```
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    authorize  @comment
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:todo_id])
    @comment.todo = @todo
    @comment.save
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    authorize @comment
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

In your controller in the destroy method you have `redirect_to root_path`. So if you add `remote: true` to your `link_to` it will be send as an AJAX request, but your controller does a redirect. The redirect will load a new page and that's why it closes the collapse.

To get the result that you wan't you shouldn't do a redirect, but rerender a small part of the view. To achieve that, you need to remove the `redirect_to root_path` from your controller. Inside your views/comments folder create a destroy.js.erb file and in there you can rerender a part of the view. A little example:

```rb
$("#id_of_html_element").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'name_of_the_partial_you_want_to_rerender') %>");
```

Now when you click on the delete link, it will go to the controller, delete the comment and then render the destroy.js.erb.
This file will look for an html element with a specific id and render a partial inside there. So there won't be a hard reload of the page and the collapse will stay open. (unless you rerender the collapse. In that case you need to call .collapse() on it)